# TempMute In discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

I would like to know how to create a temporary mute command, I mean that when I type t-mute (user) (time) a role is applied according to the time that I have established. The truth is that I have no idea how to do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function.

---

```js
// function example

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('This will be logged after a 5 second delay')
}, 5000) // 5000 is 5 seconds in ms (milliseconds)
```

---

In your situation, you can use it to add a `Muted` role, and then remove it after a specified amount of time. Assuming you're using a functional command handler, here's how you can create a `tempmute` command:

```js
// Usage: !tempmute @user [time (in milliseconds)]

// get user from mention
const target = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first())

// give user 'Muted' role
target.roles.cache.add('<ID of role you want to give>')

setTimeout(() => {

  // remove 'Muted' role
  target.roles.cache.remove('<ID of role that was given>')

}, args[1]) // trigger function after specified time
```

---

Of course, this is a very bare template, you would need to add a lot more to make it a good command.

Another suggestion would be to use the npm package [`ms`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms). `ms` is a parser that can convert various time formats to milliseconds.

---

Example:

```js
// Before:

// !tempmute @person 600000

setTimeout(() => {
  // code...
}, args[1])
```

```js
// After:

// !tempmute @person 1h

setTimeout(() => {
  // code...
}, ms(args[1]))
```

---

Hopefully, this is useful in some way.

Answer (score 3):

To set a timeout before doing something, you can use JavaScript's [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
//do something
}, afterMs)
```

I'm going to assume you already have your user and time arguments set, and the duration is to be specified in minutes.

```js
let user = args[value];
let duration = parseInt(args[value]);
setTimeout(() => {
//do something
}, duration * 60 * 1000)
```

Replace `value` with the parameter value in the message, depending on what your argument handler is like.
`parseInt()` converts the argument(string) into a number. For example, the duration specified is "5", it will become 5 after `parseInt()`.
Say, the duration specified in the message is 5(minutes), since `setTimeout()` takes in milliseconds as the duration value, we're using `duration * 60 * 1000` to convert it into milliseconds.